# Add virtual pointcloud (vpc) from https location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point-cloud

I'm trying to add a virtual point cloud file from a https-server in QGIS 3.35.0, but it seems that it only supports .copc.laz and .ept.json. I can open the vpc-file if I put it on a local directory. Is VPC supposed to be supported over https or should I convert the file to one big copc.laz?

[image]

Comment: Good question! https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2023/06/08/virtual-point-clouds/ makes it sound like you need to have the VPC file itself local but it may reference remote files. Might be worth a feature request to support remote VPC files too if that indeed is not yet supported.